# VS Code color picker for .sass files

Tags: javascript, css, sass, visual-studio-code

In the VS Code July 2017 release they have added a [color picker](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_color-picker), and state that it is available for Sass:

> For the preview, we enabled it for CSS, Sass and LESS files,
>   supporting RGBA, HSLA and Hex color modes.

The color picker does indeed work for .SCSS files but doesn't for .SASS files, is there anyway to enable the color picker to work for sass files as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I enable the VS Code Color Picker outside of CSS-like scopes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622898/how-can-i-enable-the-vs-code-color-picker-outside-of-css-like-scopes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear so.  If you don't get a better answer you can use the extension [Color Info](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.color-info) (which I was using before the Vscode July changes) and enable it for only .sass files.

```
"colorInfo.languages": [
  {
      "selector": "sass",
      "colors": ["css", "hex", "rgb"  ...........etc. ]
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure why they have provided support for syntax-color + color- picker for .SCSS and not for .SASS. I've used the color picker extension before, but I'm trying to avoid using extensions if there is something built-in that I could use.

Comment: I see no setting that would enable it.  And the docs repeatedly refer to .scss support with no mention of .sass support.  Must be difficult to support the indented syntax.

Comment: well, it seems like they wont be adding support to .sass files for this, I have slowly moving from .sass to .scss, it seems .scss is more popular.

Answer (score 1):

[VS Color Picker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lihui.vs-color-picker) works just fine. And you can even pick colors from screen into your Editor.

Answer (score 0):

VS code doesn't provide built-in support for indented sass and developers do not consider adding the feature natively.