# How can I enable the VS Code Color Picker outside of CSS-like scopes?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I mean, built-in color picker. Not extension.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76066924/836330.  The issue mentioned by @Dmitry has been closed with a commit.

Comment: Yeap. That's it.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/178242

On demo, author uses '.ts' file extension (and other extensions in the stackoverflow's answer provided by @Mark link). Cool!

Comment: @eydeeeyem I'd rather close the language-specific question as a duplicate of the more general language-agnostic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible at the moment (2018-09-29). It only works with language servers in VS Code what can provide the colors used in the currently opened file.

Here's an open issue on their GitHub with request for exactly this feature: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52364

Please upvote this request there.