# TailwindCss not showing color picker in vscode on windows

Tags: reactjs, windows, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, classname

How do I get the color palette directly in my code... Tags: TailwindCSS, React, VS Code?

I tried erasing the entire line, rewriting the code, for example, bg-[#2c2f32], but the color is not showing at the front of the bg...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I enable the VS Code Color Picker outside of CSS-like scopes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622898/how-can-i-enable-the-vs-code-color-picker-outside-of-css-like-scopes)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to install Color Highlight extension of vscode,
It will help you to identify easily which color is this and also shows the same.

ref: [color-highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=naumovs.color-highlight)