# How to add color picker in VS Code Javascript file by using rgb code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AntiAntiSepticeye.vscode-color-picker and added this code

```
"vscode-color-picker.languages": ["python", "javascript", "typescript", "typescriptreact"]
```

to settings.json in VS Code but still nothing happens.

Is there a way to do the same ?

Comment: why ask here if a better place is the repo issues

Comment: I am new, can you tell me where it is ?

Comment: go to the market place page and click the `Repository` link

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76066924/836330 for how to do this natively now - with a demo for a js file.

Comment: Note: If you want to do this without extensions, see [How can I enable the VS Code Color Picker outside of CSS-like scopes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50622898/11107541)